# Error: "TF200016" when trying to create a pull request using Visual Studio 2019 community edition

Tags: git, visual-studio, pull-request

When trying to create a pull request from within the VS2019 IDE, I get the error: **"TF200016: The following project does not exist:"**

- The developer has full access to the Azure DevOps portal and can see all projects.
- All other Git operations work fine. The developer can push a feature branch to the remote repos.
- When the developer uses the Azure DevOps portal to create a pull request he gets the error: 404 - page not found.
- We checked the output window in VS2019 and the only odd thing appears to be the message shown below:

> git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git
> --help'.

No other errors show in the output window. Any information on these elusive error will be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are still stuck with this issue or resolved but most likely the cause would be that Azure DevOps Project would have been renamed. At least that was the case for me.

The solution is I set the correct git remote repo by the command as below:

```
git remote set-url origin {URL_you_copied_from_the_remote_repo}
```

Do note that you would have to go to Azure Repo and find the correct URL before you use the above command.

Comment: Fixed my issue in VS 2022 when push was referencing a non-existent project, and also reporting that the real repo url didn't exist. Baffles me how it got into that mess...